# AngularJS - Directive can't access required ancestor's controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to access, from a directive, an ancestor's directive controller. For this, I am using the `require` property on the "child" directive, as you can see in the following code

```
mmDirectives.directive('mmMapActions', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    require : 'ˆmmSidebar',
    link : function(scope, elem, attrs, mmSidebarCtrl) {...}
  }
}
```

I have the other `mmSidebar` directive declared on the same module, and it has an associated controller, as required:

```
mmMapsDirectives.directive('mmSidebar', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    transclude : true,
    scope : {...},
    controller : function($scope) {...}
  }
}
```

I then have the following DOM

```
<div ng-controller='mmMapInteractionsController as mapInteractionsCtrl'>
  <mm-sidebar class='sidebar' ng-if='mapInteractionsCtrl.isInitialised()'
              map='mapInteractionsCtrl.map' ...>
    <mm-map-actions></mm-map-actions>
  </mm-sidebar>
</div>
```

However, I still get the old error

`Error: $compile:ctreq Missing Required Controller`

which supposedly means `mmMapActions` can't find the `mmSidebar`'s controller, but it seems everything regarding the structure of the DOM, at least, is right.

I suspect that is either having another ancestor controller `mmMapInteractionsController` or the `ng-if='...'` (although I have already tried to remove it and the same error was thrown).

What do you think is causing the error?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: use `require : '^mmSidebar',`

Comment: @vamsikrishnamannem damn! I can't believe it! I was using the wrong character! thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `ˆ` instead of `^` on the `require: ^someDirCtrl` ... Stupid, I know.